# How can I use function args to define a variable

Tags: python, discord.py

I am recoding my discord bot to make it look less spaghetti, what I want is I want to make a new function named `send_message` in here I want to set the text for `await message.author.send()`. Normally you would do `await message.author.send("Hello")` I want to make it so I can call my function and put the text in the call something like this `send_message(text="hello!")`

Here is my code

```
async def send_message(self, message, text):
    await message.author.send(text)

send_message(text="Hello")
```

This is not working and I can't seem to figure out why, the `method` argument is used for `message.author.send` and `self` is used for `author`

Comment: You still need to provide an argument for the `message` parameter.

Comment: You also need to call it as `someobj.send_message`, even though you aren't using the `self` parameter in the body

Comment: but `message.author` is something that comes with the discord.py library so I don't see what I'd have ot provide

Comment: Then `message` doesn't have to be a function parameter; you are accessing it as a global, apparently.

Comment: Is this a method of an object or a stand-alone function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working since the `message` and `text` args are both posional, required arguments. You don't specify those in the method call.
As far as I see the `message` can't be empty since you are using it in the method. For the `text` you can do the following.

```py
async def send_message(text=''):
    await message.author.send(text)

send_message(text="Hello")
```